# Time complexity question 3 loops + if statement

Tags: for-loop, time-complexity

I have some trouble finding the time complexity of the code below. I figured that the `if` statement will run for approximately `n` times; however, I could not manage to describe it mathematically. Thanks in advance.

```
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 1 ; j < i*i; j++) {
        if (j % i == 0) {
            for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
                sum++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Outer loop

Well, it's clear that it's O(n) because `i` is bounded by `n`.

#### Inner loops

If we take a look at the second loop alone, then it looks as follows:

```
...
for (int j = 1 ; j < i*i; j++){
...
```

`j` is bounded by `i*i` or simply `n^2`.

However, the innermost loop won't be executed for every `j`, but only for `j`s that are divisible by `i` because that's what the constraint `j % i == 0` means. Since `j ~ i*i`, there will be only `i` cases, when the innermost loop is executed.  So, the number of iterations in the inner loops is bounded by `i^3` or simply `n^3`.

#### Result

Hence, the overall time complexity is O(n<sup>4</sup>).